# What projection to use for Google Maps?

Tags: geoserver, google-maps

I'm loading a WMS layer which comes in WGS84 into Google Maps. From what I've read so far, I should reproject this layer to Google Pseudo Mercator (either 3857/900913). However, when I save the layer in either one of those two projections, it is not displayed in Google Maps, but I can view it in Data Preview of Geoserver. Others with WGS84 are displayed correctly but with a position shift.

Do I really need to reproject the layer? I'm not sure whether it is not just a matter of some inaccuracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're correct, to display the data it will need to be in the Google Mercator projection (3857/900913). Is your data displaying if it's not being reprojected though?

Comment: Yes, if I import the .shp file into Geoserver with WGS84 projection, I can view it on a map. However, if I upload the file with EPSG:900913, I can't, although I have changed getMap parameters to request epsg:900913 instead of epsg:4326.

Or should I import the epsg:4326 shp and reproject it into wgs84?

Comment: When you're importing the file, are you just setting the projection on the data to be 900913, or reprojecting the data to this projection? Sounds like it might be the former in which case the data will become mismatched with the projection it is in which might explain why it doesn't appear on the map.

Comment: I solved it by changing the JS script, as it was expecting the input to be in epsg:4326. Thank you.